# How to Create Custom Message Box Template

Tags: wpf, xaml

How can I create a custom message box as the default message box in WPF doesn't work for me!

[image: My Message box]

Comment: You could create a custom window: https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/03/16/how-to-create-a-custom-window-in-wpf/

Answer (score 3):

Here's a good [tutorial](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1081930/Custom-Message-Box-in-WPF-XAML) on creating your own MessageBox.